# Regular Expression - Validate a number

Tags: regex, validation

I need to know how can I validate a number, but it's not any number, I need to validate this:

If the number is **0** or if number is **between 0.50 and 100**

I can allow 0 and any other number (with or without decimals, if have, at max 2 decimals), but it has to be between 0.50 and 100.

I've got this:

```
^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$
```

But it validates any number, and I can't do that.

I need to validate it in a single expression, can someone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: so to be clear, the number can only be between 0 and 100 and may have a decimal but if it has a decimal, it must be between .50 and .99 ? also, can you have 100.52 or is 100 the absolute max?

Comment: If it's a number, why are you treating it as a string? Every language or framework I've used has a method to attempt to parse a string into one or more numeric types; once doing that, you can use mathematical & logical operators like `(x == 0) || (x >= 0.50 && x <= 100)`.

Comment: No, the number can be 0 or between 0.50 and 100, it can have decimals (except 100 wich is the max)

Comment: Should you really be using a regex for this? (see @alroc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one will work for you :

```
^((?:10)?0|0\.(?:[5-9]\d?)|(?:[1-9]|[1-9]\d)(?:\.\d{1,2})?)$
```

Details :

- `(?:10)?0` : special cases for 0 and 100
- `0\.(?:[5-9]\d?)` : match 0.50 to 0.99 (including 0.5, 0.6...)
- `(?:[1-9]|[1-9]\d)(?:\.\d{1,2})` :

  - `(?:[1-9]|[1-9]\d)` : integer part, match 1 to 9, and 10 to 99
  - `(?:\.\d{1,2})` : decimal part, match 00 to 99 (including 0, 1, 2...)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/nakeqR_M8Bja_5G7)

Comment: @zessx Thanks, it works, I checked some numbers, and it worked!, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
^0$|^100$|^(([1-9]{1}[0-9]?)(\.\d{1,2})?)$|^0\.[5-9]{1}(\d?)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/2DGbqjHGxjDFu8CV)

Comment: Not match with 0, I need exactly what you did (between 0.5 and 100) but 0 (without decimals) has to be valid too, but this is great :)

Comment: I changed a bit, this works thanks `^0$|^100$|^(([1-9]{1}|[0-9]{2})(\.\d{0,2})?)$|^0.5(\d{0,1})$`

Comment: @AlexFilipovici Doesn't match 0.60~0.99

Comment: @zessx That's true, and it match with 00.10 but it shouldn't.

Comment: @David have a look on my answer

Comment: @zessx, have you actually verified the current expression? I modifed it a few times after my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

`^(100|0|0?\.[5-9][0-9]?|[1-9][0-9]?(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?)$`

Comment: Doesn't match `0.50`.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici well okay, added in optionals to allow `.5` `.50` `0.5` `0.50`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the way to write it:

```
^100|[1-9]{1,2}(\\.[0-9]{0,2})?|0(\\.[5-9][0-9])?)$
```

altough looks pretty akward.

LE:

```
^0$|^100$|^0\\.[5-9]\\d?$|^([1-9]|\\d{2})(\\.\\d{1,2})?$
```

matches: 0, 100, 0.50, 0.5, 1, 1.0, 1.15, etc.